# Why we should not discuss new theories?

Tags: discussion, scope

I heard recently that we should not discuss new theories here. Why we should not discuss new theories when they are very closely resembling the existing accepted theories but with slight modification. After all even if we fail with new theory, we end up learing the old established theory in a better way.

Comment: New published theories are OK. See [Is non mainstream physics appropriate here?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site) for more information.

Comment: @Manishearth : For example are these type of questions okay, say we  modify the schrodinger equation a bit like this and change the born rule a bit like this and see the new predictions and discuss them. I mean the question will self contained and within the scope of reader who knows QM, are these questions welcome?

Comment: If you are working within the realm of established theory/formulism it is OK. However, if you want to propose a newish theory and discuss the validity, that is not.

Comment: @Manishearth :  just wonder, is  there any physics forum to discuss new theories.

Comment: Try the associated chat room for this site. Not sure if any other forums exist, but _usually_ when someone claims to have a "new theory" and is looking to the internet first (as opposed to physicists who discuss with collaborators/etc), the theory is not really a sound one and most sites don't want people to promote fringe theories so they disallow "I have a new theory" posts.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the key point emerges in your comment above:

> is there any physics forum to discuss new theories

This is not a discussion forum - it is a question and answer site. It's hard to see how you could ask a question about a new theory without it turning into a discussion. That doesn't mean we hate and revile speculation, just that this isn't the place for it.

I must admit I'm a bit uncomfortable with the phrase "non-mainstream physics" because I'm sure that's how Pope Urban VIII would have described Galileo. Actually I think the wording on the vote to close dialog is pretty good when it says:

> Questions about the general correctness of unpublished personal theories are off topic, although specific questions evaluating new theories in the context of established science are usually allowed.